# How to get Foldername into the output txt file of Using Out-File or ">" in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, directory

I am doing a command line approach for making a filename content into txt file.

Here's what I've got right now.

I have got the `dir` command to get the names and exclude the .txt files in the folder I want to output. I was able to sort files by name using the `sort-object` command. And the `out-file` I've written down there is just to open up what I'm doing right now.

```
dir -n -exclude *.txt | sort-object | out-file -confirm .\<current foldername>.txt
```

However I want this command line to output it's unique foldername as in lets say an address is "..\folder\" & "..\folder2\" and I want to use `out-file` or `>` command in such a way that it creates folder.txt and folder2.txt, on different and multiple filetypes. Mind you I'm not talking about "**filepath**" for .txt filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
dir -n -Exclude *.txt |Sort-Object|Out-File -Confirm "$((Get-Item .).Name).txt"
```

Between the "" the filename is constructed. This is what happens:

- The "" indicate it is a string
- Within a string it is possible to embed an expression
- The expression that is embedded here is `(Get-Item .).Name` that gets the name of the current directory (.)
- To embed code in a string you have to format like this: `$(<embedded code block>)`
- After the embedded code the string literal .txt is added

Comment: Thank you. The -wi I ran gave the correct result. While at it could you please guide me to the syntax at the end. It's a bit bleak for me to understand the rest of code. `"$((Get-Item .).Name).txt"` this part to be exact.

Comment: @AtaYiğitTelli Just added some explanation to my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for the extra explanation @Gert much appreciated